# Is there a rule specifies range of syscall number? (on x86)

Tags: system-calls

Is there minimum or maximum value of syscall number? If there is, what is the value? Is it just 0 and 0xffffffff? If not, where is the rule specifies the range?

Comment: The ['syscall'](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) uses the ABI, whatever that is, for a given system (which *includes* the operating system and CPU mode). I would thus expect the maximum value to *generally* be what can fit in a register (for a given ..), but far fewer numbers are actually used. And for a "specific rule" .. meh. Use the numbers that represent a valid call and move on.

Comment: Let me show you an example, I could write a kernel module uses unused syscall number. Then what range could the syscall number be? And the system is x86 in Linux